# Transformable Attributes in Core Data using Swift 3

Tags: core-data, swift3, xcode9, transformable

I have a Core Data model with a multiple transformable attribute. I also have this attribute use a custom NSValueTransformer, setup in the model properly. I can not found any example of transformable attribute using core date for Swift 3.

- How to create transformable object in NSManagedObject class?
- How to create a string transformable and save in core data and fetch
  the details from core data?

Is there any blog example of this?

Comment: This should work the same as it ever did. What problems are you having that you can't solve the same way you solved this problem in the past?